# Angular6: load localeId depending upon environment variable

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, angular6, locale

I am loading localeId in angular 6 as:

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localePt from '@angular/common/locales/pt';

registerLocaleData(localePt);

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'pt-BR' }    
  ]  
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But I have to load different languages Locales like `en, nb, fr, he` depending upon env variables.
Please tell me how do I do it.

NOTE: I checked some solutions from angular5 but that won't work because in angular6 we need to import particular locale and register it using `registerLocaleData`

Comment: The browser doesn't provide any environment variable. And Angular code executes in the browser, so... And even if the browser did provide environment variables, do you really expect every user of your webapp to configure environment variables to get the app in the right language? What do you *actually* want to achieve?

Comment: @JBNizet I am not talking of browser-related env variable, I am talking of angular env variable.

Comment: `useValue: environment.locale`? And call registerLocaleData from within the environment.xxx.ts file?

Comment: so you mean to say I should write the import of locale and register in env file?